# Can't start webcam for google video services

Tags: webcam, google-talk, google-video

I've got Ubuntu 11.10 64 bit and have installed the google video chat plugin. However webcam doesn't seem to work (black screen -- no video at all).
 For cheese it works but shows really bad (black and white kinda) image.
 Following some link I installed guvcview if I start it then image looks neat.

Any suggestions on how can it be fixed?

If it helps I've tried the solution:

```
$ sudo mv /opt/google/talkplugin/GoogleTalkPlugin /opt/google/talkplugin/GoogleTalkPlugin.old
$ sudo gedit /opt/google/talkplugin/GoogleTalkPlugin
```

and putting following lines in:

```
#!/bin/sh
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib32/libv4l/v4l1compat.so /opt/google/talkplugin/GoogleTalkPlugin.old
```

OR

```
#!/bin/sh
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so /opt/google/talkplugin/GoogleTalkPlugin.old
```

Cause I've both files.
Finally

```
$sudo chmod +x /opt/google/talkplugin/GoogleTalkPlugin.old
```

I closed and reopened chrome then started gmail tried video call -- black screen :-/

Ok so today finally google+ provided me with trouble shoot link and advised me:

> > The plug-in won't install
>
> If you're having trouble installing the plug-in, or are receiving a
>   message asking you to reinstall it, you should check to make sure your
>   configuration is right. To do so simply:
>
> ```
> Check to make sure the Google Talk Plugin Video Accelerator and Google Talk NPAPI Plugin are enabled. If you're using Chrome you can
> ```
>
> type about:plugins in your browser to display your plug-ins.
>       Make sure you're not using Internet Explorer 64-bit (this is a browser version that is 64 bit as opposed to 32 bit).
>       Ensure that you don't have any "click to run" extensions enabled.
>
> If you're still experiencing this issue after checking your
>   configuration you can follow these steps:
>
> ```
> Refresh the browser page.
> Close any running Google Talk plug-in processes.
> Close all open and running browser processes.
> Restart your computer.
> Uninstall and then reinstall the plug-in.
> Try a different browser such as Google Chrome or Mozilla Firefox.
> ```

I looked in about:plugins for chrome and firefox:
I don't have Google Talk NPAPI Plugin, does that matter? and I thought its installed with google talk plugin or no?

Comment: OK so google talk plugin for video chat works with google chrome only and prerequisite is firefox should not be running simultaneously. I tried google video chat with chrome many time but failed but today is first time I tried it without running firefox. So how does it matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yesterday got an update for googletalk-plugin and I see video services for google started working :)